# Why does my function that calls exec on marshalled code give an error about globals?

Tags: python, exec

While playing around with [`compile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#compile), [the marshal module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/marshal.html), and [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement). I've encountered some confusing behavior. Consider  `simple.py`

```
def foo():
    print "Inside foo()..."

def main():
    print "This is a simple script that should count to 3."

    for i in range(1, 4):
        print "This is iteration number", i

    foo()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I run this script using `exec` like this

```
with open('simple.py', 'r') as f:
    code = f.read()
exec code
```

it gives the expected output.

```
This is a simple script that should count to 3.
This is iteration number 1
This is iteration number 2
This is iteration number 3
Inside foo()...
```

However, when if I introduce `compile()`, `marshal.dump()`, and `marshal.load()` like this

```
import marshal

def runme(file):
    with open(file, "r") as f:
        code = marshal.load(f)
    exec code

with open("simple.py", "r") as f:
    contents = f.read()

code = compile(contents, "simple.py", "exec")
with open("marshalled", "w") as f:  
    marshal.dump(code, f)

runme("marshalled")
```

it prints the beginning of the expected output and then errors out

```
This is a simple script that should count to 3.
This is iteration number 1
This is iteration number 2
This is iteration number 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./exec_within_function.py", line 17, in <module>
    runme("marshalled")
  File "./exec_within_function.py", line 8, in runme
    exec code
  File "simple.py", line 15, in <module>
    main()
  File "simple.py", line 12, in main
    foo()
NameError: global name 'foo' is not defined
```

Why does it say that `foo` is not defined?

In order to understand, I tried using `dir()` like this

```
import simple # imports simple.py
dir(simple)
```

and as expected, it shows that `foo` is defined.

```
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'foo', 'main']
```

I've also noticed that when I use `dis.dis()` on the deserialized code object (read via `marshal.load()`), the only thing I see is the `LOAD_NAME` and `CALL_FUNCTION` for `main()`, but when I do it with `import` like this

```
import dis, sys

import simple
dis.dis(sys.modules["simple"])
```

it gives me the entire disassembly as expected.

I've even looked at [some of the code that python uses for compiling](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/py_compile.py) and although I think `import` uses some sort of lookup table for definitions, I'm not sure what the difference is with `compile()` that's causing this behavior.

Comment: What do you mean? The following seems to work:
    with open('simple.py', 'r') as f:
        code = f.read()
        
    with open('simple.mash', 'w') as f:
        marshal.dump(code, f)

    with open('simple.mash', 'r') as f:
        code = marshal.load(f)

    exec code

Comment: Before you `marshal.dump()` the code to simple.mash, try running `compile()` on it, then `marshal.dump()` the resulting code object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script successfully exercises your simple.py code 3 times. Does this clarify anything? Or am I misunderstanding your question?

```
# from original example
with open('simple.py', 'r') as f:
    code = f.read()
exec(code)
# compile and run again
a = compile(code, "simple_compiled_this_file_not_created", "exec")
exec(a)
# marshal and unmarshal
import marshal
f = open("./marshalfoo.bin", "wb")
marshal.dump(a,f) 
f.close()
b = marshal.load(open("./marshalfoo.bin", "rb"))
exec(b)
```

Comment: Interesting. So I was able to track down my issue based on your code. It would appear that if I try to `exec()` the code from inside a function, it fails (eg after being run through `compile()` I call a function I created called `runme()` that actually calls `exec()` on the resulting code object). What's even more interesting is if I call `exec()` from the same scope as `compile()` and then call `runme()` is that it works fine. So its for sure a scoping issue.

Comment: For anyone who cares, I got this to work as expected by placing the code inside simple.py inside a custom class (I called it Simple), and then in the `if __name__ == "__main__"` doing `s= Simple()` and `s.main()`. After that the code appears to work fine from any scope.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does it say that `foo` is not defined?

This much smaller example gives the same error

```
with open("simple.py", "r") as f:
    code = f.read()

def wrap_exec(code):
    exec code

wrap_exec(code)
```

but this one doesn't.

```
with open("simple.py", "r") as f:
    code = f.read()

exec code
```

If you hadn't already guessed, the problem occurs when you call `exec` from within a function.

To find the best explanations and solutions for that, look at the answers to [*Why exec() works differently when invoked inside of function and how to avoid it*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55763182/7246614). For completeness, below is how I recommend you solve it in this case.

Since you have access to changing the `exec`ed code (`simple.py` in this example), the problem can easily be solved by adding a `global` declaration.

```
global foo # added

def foo():
    print "Inside foo()..."

def main():
    print "This is a simple script that should count to 3."

    for i in range(1, 4):
        print "This is iteration number", i

    foo()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

With regards to why `dir(simple)` still shows `foo`, it's actually because you `import`ed `simple.py` rather than `exec`ing its contents. Not only does `foo` appear in the output of `dir()`, but the program works when you use `import`.

```
import simple
simple.main()
```

If this surprises you, it's because when you `import` something, Python treats it as a module. Within a module things declared at the top level are automatically made global.

With regards to the confusing outputs of `dis.dis`, I couldn't reproduce that behavior so I can't study it and provide an explanation.